# logstash 5.1.1 installation error?

Tags: installation, logstash

After executing the logstash.bat file in bin folder i am getting the following errros:

> Could not find log4j2 configuration at path
>   /Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/config/log4j2.properties. Using
>   default config which logs to console 15:41:06.440 [LogStash::Runner]
>   INFO  logstash.agent - No config files found in path {:pa
>   th=>"C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/bin/logstash-simple.conf"}
>   15:41:06.440 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - failed to fetch
>   pipeline configura tion {:message=>"No config files found:
>   logstash-simple.conf. Can you make sure this path  is a logstash
>   config file?"}

Comment: can anyone help me in sorting out this problem??

Comment: what i didnt get you??

Comment: I've updated a work around. Let me know if it works!

Comment: can u pls expalin in detail i am new to this environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try and add the following line in your `setup.bat` within your `bin` folder as follows:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.configurationFile=%LS_HOME%\config\log4j2.properties
```

This [issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6352) with the lastest versions is still on. Might be [helpful](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/info-windows-logstash-and-could-not-find-log4j2-configuration/67633) as well.

Comment: in setup.bat file i have so many JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% these things i dont know for what exactly it have give this command which u had mentioned above

Comment: Add this as a new line, where you might see similar commands been set there. You could add this under it.

Comment: sry,i forgot to do it